# Formal algorithm that accepts two finite automatons and outputs finite automaton

Tags: automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

Formally, I have

Language $L_1 \subseteq \{a,b,c\}^*$

Language $L2 \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$

and a function $bin: \{a,b,c\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ defined as follows    $$bin(\epsilon) = \epsilon$$
$$bin(a) = 00$$
$$bin(b) = 01$$
$$bin(c) = 11$$

I am supposed to design and formally write down an algorithm that accepts two finite automatons (that may be non-deterministic) $M_1 = (Q_1, \{a,b,c\}, \delta_1, q_{01}, F_1)$ and $M_2 = (Q_2, \{0,1\}, \delta_2, q_{02}, F_2)$ and outputs one finite automaton $M_f$ where $L(M_f) = \{ w \mid w \in L(M_1) \wedge bin(w) \in L(M_2)\}$.

Where:

$w$ is string that is contained in language L, generated (or accepted?) by automaton $M_f$.

$\wedge$ stands for conjunction

What is the approach I apply for this task? I searched the internet for possible algorithms and I always end up empty handed, mainly because there is that $bin(.)$ function in the resulting $L(M_f)$ description.

Could anyone please hint me up on where to start with task like this?

Comment: This is just the intersection of 2 automatons.  Pipe the input into M1 and bin, and from bin into M2, and only accept when they both accept.  You are making it way more complicated than it actually is with all the symbols and words.

Comment: @DanielV Thank you for your time to reply. Unfortunately this is one of exercises for the class I am taking and I believe they make it hard to understand on purpose. Would it be possible for you to write me an answer that would describe the process in which you found out that it is actually an intersection and how do I have to pipe it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielV said, this is just an intersection. However it is a bit more complicated since the two automaton do not have the same input alphabet.

There are two possible strategies to answer your problem:
The first is to directly build $M_f$ it can be messy but it is doable.
The second strategy, a bit longer but easier is to compute an automaton $M_2'$ such that $L(M_2')=\{w\in\{a,b,c\}^*\mid bin(w)\in L(M_2)\}$. And then build $M_f$ as the intersection of $M_1$ and $M_2'$.

Do you think you can design such $M_2'$? If not please ask, I would give you some more hints.

**Edit: Hint to build $M_2'$**

Consider the automaton $M_2'=(Q_2\cup (Q_2\times\{0,1\}),\delta,q_{02},F_2)$
with: $\forall q\in Q_2$,
$$\delta(q,\epsilon)=(\delta_2(q,0),0)$$
$$\delta(q,\epsilon)=(\delta_2(q,1),1)$$
$$\delta((q,0),a)=\delta_2(q,0)$$
$$\delta((q,0),b)=\delta_2(q,1)$$
$$\delta((q,1),c)=\delta_2(q,1)$$

Can you show that $L(M_2')=\{w\in\{a,b,c\}^*\mid bin(w)\in L(M_2)\}$?

Comment: I am not really sure where to begin with the construction. I will move between states with `a`, `b`, or `c` where after applying bin() function on the resulting (accepted?) string I will get something that fits into L2. Also how does "the guid Mf and the intersection of M1 and M'2" helps (I dont understand that). Then there is the thing with need for "formally written algorithm", please help me some more.

Comment: @FanaticD it is "then build $M_f$ as the intersection of $M_1$ and $M_2'$". Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @FanaticD I added an Hint to help you. For the formally written algorithm it will go as follow: given $M_1$ $M_2$, build $M_2'$ as follow return the intersection of $M_1$ and $M_2'$.

Comment: It seems like we were finally able to solve the problem, using your algorithm. I appreciate your help and marking your post as an answer. Thank you very much.